# Array.Exists - Possible bug?

Tags: c#, arrays, mono

I was recently trying to complete a pretty good LeetCode exercise, and I can say that the solution I'm trying to use is not the best, but it's still been good practice. However, I noticed when using the Array.Exists function, I don't get consistent results as I'd expect when debugging with Console.WriteLine. Granted, I'm using this on a jagged array, but I would THINK that this would work, iterating on an array line by line. Considering the following example 2D array:

```
[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
```

Given this array, you would THINK that when iterating through the array, you would be able to use Array.Exists to find that there IS, indeed, a 1 AND a 0 each subsequent sub-array, like when running these lines:

```
Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists<int>(grid[i], x => x.Equals(0)));
Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists<int>(grid[i], x => x.Equals(1)));
```

I would expect to return the following while looping through the array with i and j iterators:

```
True
True
```

However, when moving from the FIRST sub-array (grid[0] onto grid[1], for example), I would get false negatives, as if there was indeed no 1 in the array, which we know is false:

```
True
False
```

These should both be true in this jagged array, but apparently it's not, at least on the LeetCode website.

Is anyone else able to replicate this?

Here's a small program that shows the issue I'm talking about when run in a console application:

```
using System;

public class Solution {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {

        int[][] exampleGrid = new int[][]
        {
            new int[] {2,0},
            new int[] {1,0}
        };

        Solution.Feedback(exampleGrid);

    }

    public static void Feedback(int[][] grid) {
          for(int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists<int>(grid[i], x => x.Equals(0)));
              Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists<int>(grid[i], x => x.Equals(1)));
           }
  }
}
```

Please note: this only appears to be reproducible in mono 5.18.0 - C# 7.

Comment: "2d array" and `grid[i]` don't align... Are you sure you are talking about 2d array (`int [ , ]`) and not about jagged array (`int[][]`)? Showing actual [MCVE] which includes array definition/initialization could help.

Comment: Hi Alexei, you're right, it's a jagged array. I know this is closed, but for what it's worth I did update above, and can verify that I CANNOT reproduce this issue on any compiler other than the mono one that LeetCode has.

Comment: The expected output from your sample `Solution.Feedback()` is `True, False, True, True`. That's what I get - are you saying that's NOT what you get? (Incidentally, when posting samples like that it's useful to clearly state EXPECTED RESULT: x and ACTUAL RESULT: y.)

Comment: Hi Matthew, yes. It's NOT what I get on the Leetcode site for some reason. But it DOES work as expected on other online C# consoles like this one: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm it's definitely not a compiler bug of any sort, but the code itself. I was unable to replicate on Leetcode itself on their playground.

And then I discovered it was definitely a bug of my own. Go figure!

For those that wish to find my bug, give any input, or something different otherwise, feel free to go here:

https://leetcode.com/playground/PSz4zMzL

But this is not the scope of this post anymore - so I'll just move along.